# Firestore query: Order by count after a certain date

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Supposing a collection of a large number of documents like this:

```js
{
  createdAt: 1630789008561, // timestamp
  count: 5
},
{
  createdAt: 1630788666511, // timestamp
  count: 50
},
...
```

**I would like to query the 50 documents with the highest count that were created after a certain timestamp.**

One simple solution is to query all documents after this certain timestamp and then order them yourself. But I can't since my database is too large.

My first query attempt was:

```js
db.collection("docs")
  .where("createdAt", ">", timestamp)
  .orderBy("count", "desc")
  .limit(50)
  .get();
```

This query does not work in Firestore and throws:

> Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: inequality filter property and first sort order must be the same: createdAt and count`

I then tried:

```js
db.collection("docs")
  .where("createdAt", ">", timestamp)
  .orderBy("createdAt", "desc")
  .orderBy("count", "desc")
  .limit(50)
  .get()
```

This query will not work for me since what it does is taking 50 documents after the timestamp and then order these by count in case they have the same timestamp, which is not what I want.

**Edit on why this query does not work:**

If I have 150 documents:

- 50 created on day 1 with a count of 1
- 50 created on day 2 with a count of 2
- 50 created on day 3 with a count of 1

If I use this query with a timestamp of 0, I would get back the 50 documents last created (because I am using `.orderBy("createdAt", "desc")`) which have a count of 1 and are obviously not the ones with the highest count.
If you use `asc` instead, you get the first documents, which still have not the highest count.
I would like a query that for a timestamp of 0 would give me the 50 documents with the count of 2.

How can I achieve what I want?

**EDIT on solution I am currently using (which I'd like to change):**

Since my time range is a day, I add a `day` field in every documents like this:

```js
{
  day: '2021-09-06',
  createdAt: 1630789008561, // timestamp
  count: 5
},
{
  day: '2021-09-05',
  createdAt: 1630788666511, // timestamp
  count: 50
},
...
```

I can then do an equality check like this:

```
db
  .collection("docs")
  .where("day", "==", '2021-09-05')
  .orderBy("count", "desc")
  .limit(50)
  .get();
```

This works but this is not great since everytime my time range changes I need to update my db schema and update every documents with the new field.

Answer (score -2):

Return the first 50 docs sorted by count. Then you filter by timestamp on the device.

```
QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> query = await db
    .collection("docs")
    .orderBy("count", "desc")
    .limit(50)
    .get();
List docs = query.docs.map((e) => e.data()).toList();
// then filter by timestamp on the device
docs.removeWhere((element) => element['createdAt'] < timestamp);
```

This cannot be done by using where query because there is no way around this [limitation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data).

> If you include a filter with a range comparison (<, <=, >, >=), your first ordering must be on the same field:

Comment: This query would fetch the documents with the highest count overall and THEN you (by chance) would pick any that are in the desired time period: that is not what I need because if the 50 documents with the highest count are NOT within the desired period, then you get nothing at the end.

Comment: I understand your point, but there is no way to get what you want because of the limitation I pointed out. Another option is to get all docs after a timestamp then filter by count on the device.

Comment: Unfortunately, I was aware of the limitation when writing my post, what I am looking for is a solution for this use case. Your other option is impossible in a real world application with millions of documents.

Answer (score -2):

this is the right query.

```
db.collection("docs")
 .where("createdAt", ">", timestamp)
 .orderBy("createdAt", "desc")
 .orderBy("count", "desc")
 .limit(50)
 .get()
```

But you need to set Firestore Composite Indexes.

Comment: I did create an index but this query does not do what I need. It fetches 50 documents after the date and THEN sort them by count (if they have the same timestamp). So you do not end up with the documents with highest count in that period.